# Creating table when using in-memory database

Tags: hibernate, derby

I am using Hibernate for connecting to derby . i am using derby as an in-memory database for my application. I am completely new to hibernate and derby stuff. I have two xml files, sample.cfg.xml and sample.hbm.xml. The sample.hbm.xml contains the mapping between the table and the bean class. I am setting the in-memory db as follows:

```
       Dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect
       DriverClassName = org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
       Url= jdbc:derby:unitTestDB;create=true
       UserName = ""
       Password=""
```

My question is , will the table be automatically created ? (by using the sample.hbm.xml as a reference) or do i need to create the table separately ? Pardon my ignorance as i am completely new to this.

Answer (score 2):

By default tables are not automatically created. Tables will be created if you advice Hibernate to do so by giving needed value for `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` attribute in configuration (properties in same place where you have other properties that you listed in query).

Most likely for development *create-drop* is best options in general, every time you deploy you will start with fresh database. For in-memory it is of course always fresh. Other options are: *validate*, *update* and *create*.